# Secure usage of FileStreams

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an encryption program for fun. I stumbled across the problem, that a deleted file has not to be gone even if it is overwritten by opening it with a `FileStream` and writing a bunch of random bytes into it.

But my current implementation of my program is creating a new temporary file, to write encrypted/decrypted data into it to save RAM. I was now wondering if the same problem does apply, even if I don't terminate the `FileStream` object, which exists since the files creation.

So if I just set my stream position back to zero and overwrite every single byte, does it really write onto the same positions as in the beginning or can parts of the temp file survive? If so, is there any workaround I could use?

My current approach:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
fileStream.Write(//possible decrypted data);

fileStream.Position = 0;

byte[] bytes = RandomBytes();
long amount = (fileStream.Length / bytes.Length + 1);

for (long i = 0; i < amount; i++)
{
    fileStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}

string name = fileStream.Name;
fileStream.Close();
File.Delete(name);
```

Comment: Security is a compromise, there is no such thing as absolute security. You have to accept some flaw and then try to either add another layer of security (with its own flaw) to mitigate the risk or accept the risk. Be aware that there's a ton of details in the file system that will trip you up. For instance, if the file is on SSD, overwriting it might not actually overwrite the original data at all, it may instead move the parts of the file that you overwrite to other parts of the disk, leaving the old parts to garbage collection (SSD TRIM).

Comment: The problem is not the software. It is much deeper within the hardware. On a SSD you say, you'd like to write on sector 17, but that address is virtual and will be mapped to a physical sector on-the-fly. When you in another step (doesn't matter, if it is the same file stream or not, cause the drive doesn't know about how you access these things) say you'd like to overwrite that sector, it simply marks the physical sector as deleted and maps another physical sector to this virtual address. All sectors will be used in round-robin, so there is no chance to overwrite a specific physical sector.

Comment: The first question you should answer (for yourself) is this: *Who* or *what* are you trying to protect something *from* or *for*. Once you know that, start looking at which risks you face and then try to mitigate them.

Comment: Additionally to the comments about SSDs, you have in-memory caches, on-disk caching, disk reorganization (which may leave copies of the file lying around out of your control), memory copies (that isn't counted as caches, just old data lying around in memory).

Comment: Also, even if you succeeded in having a solution to deleting and overwriting the file, what if someone stole a copy of the data before you got to that? What if a program with low-level access read the file contents before you overwrote and deleted the file?

Comment: So what i take out of this, is that this solution is not nearly as secure as i hoped it would be. But im still curious how current encryption software is handling secure deletion. Are they doing something similar to sdelet and acces the defragmentation API or are there other tricks they apply?

Comment: My goal with this program was to transport encrypted data on f.e. on a usb drive, be able to access the information and get rid of it afterwards, so i dont have to worry if i should lose the drive.

Comment: If its encrypted and you lose the drive...assuming your encryption is good...that should be enough to prevent them from reading the data.